# How to apply and remove discount

Tags: jquery

I want to show the price (dynamic value) and I want to have a checkbox which, if clicked, will apply 15% discount.

But if it's unclicked, the value should be the whole amount

```js
  $("#discount").click(function() {
    var value = $('p').text()
    if ($('#discount').is(':checked')) {
      var intValue = parseInt(value)
      var percentValue = intValue-(intValue*15/100)
      $('p').text(percentValue)
    } else {
      $('p').text(value)
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>500</p>

<input type="checkbox" id="discount" name="discount" value="discount"> Discount
```

How do I get my initial value if somebody unclicks the checkbox?

Thanks!

Comment: You can save the previous value in a hidden field and can replace on unchecking a database

Comment: Check my answer if you don't want to save the original value anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the original price in a hidden field and access it on unchecking a checkbox, something like this:

```js
  $("#discount").click(function() {
    var value = $('p').text()
    if ($('#discount').is(':checked')) {
      var intValue = parseInt(value)
      var percentValue = intValue-(intValue*15/100)
      $('p').text(percentValue)
    } else {
      var val=$("#hdnOriginalPrice").val();
      $('p').text(val)
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>500</p>
 <input type="hidden" id="hdnOriginalPrice" value="500"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="discount" name="discount" value="discount"> Discount
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to store the original price somewhere that is unaffected by the calculation. To do that you could use a `data` attribute, something like this:

```js
$("#discount").change(function() {
  var checked = this.checked;

  $('p').text(function() {
    var original = $(this).data('original');
    return checked ? original - (original * 15 / 100) : original;
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p data-original="500">500</p>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="discount" name="discount" value="discount">
  Discount
</label>
```

Note that I tidied the code slightly by using a `change` event handler (which is better practice for checkboxes and radio buttons), wrapping the checkbox in a `label` to increase the size of the hit area, and using the `text()` method's callback to simplify the logic as well as reduce the number of selectors. You also don't need to explicitly cast the price to an integer as `data()` will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the base price in a `data` attribute and use it later with jQuery [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function :

```js
$("#discount").on('change', function() {
  let value = +$('p').attr('data-base-price');
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    let percentValue = value - (value * 15 / 100)
    $('p').text(percentValue)
  } else {
    $('p').text(value)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p data-base-price="500">500</p>

<input type="checkbox" id="discount" name="discount" value="discount"> Discount
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var original_value = $('p').text();  // Get the original value before it changes.
  $("#discount").click(function() {
    var value = $('p').text();
    if ($('#discount').is(':checked')) {
      var intValue = parseInt(value)
      var percentValue = intValue-(intValue*15/100)
      $('p').text(percentValue)
    } else {
      $('p').text(original_value);    // Changed this line.
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>500</p>

<input type="checkbox" id="discount" name="discount" value="discount"> Discount
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a hidden field and save the value in it.

An alternative approach would be to use mathematics to get the actual value, without storing it anywhere.

> Actual value = (Discounted value / (1-(percent/100)));

```js
  var discount = 15;
  $("#discount").click(function() {
    var value = $('p').text()
    if ($('#discount').is(':checked')) {
      var intValue = parseInt(value)
      var percentValue = intValue-(intValue*discount/100)
      $('p').text(percentValue)
    } else {
      $('p').text(value / (1-discount/100))
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>500</p>

<input type="checkbox" id="discount" name="discount" value="discount"> Discount
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is take a global variable and assign the value to that variable before doing any computation. Then, if the checkbox is unchecked you can set that value and it works perfectly for you.

```js
var parsedAmount;
$("#discount").click(function() {
    value = $('p').text();
    debugger
    if ($('#discount').is(':checked')) {
      parsedAmount = parseInt(value)
      var percentValue = parsedAmount-(parsedAmount*15/100)
      $('p').text(percentValue)
    } else {
      $('p').text(parsedAmount)
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>500</p>

<input type="checkbox" id="discount" name="discount" value="discount"> Discount
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="base_price">200</p>
<input type="hidden" name="discount" value= '15' id="discount">
<input type="checkbox" name="discCheck" id= "discCheck">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var base_price = $('#base_price').text();

    $( '#discCheck' ).click(function(){ 
          if( $('#discCheck' ).is(':checked')){
                var discVal = $('#discount').val();
                var calDiscount = base_price -(base_price *15/100);
                 $('#base_price').text(calDiscount);
          } else { $('#base_price').text(base_price); };
        }); 
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```